# AngularJS ng-repeat over data with # keys

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

The data i'm trying to iterate over looks like this:

```
    {
            "request": "Stream/GetDigest",
            "response": {
                "success": true,
                "content": {
                    "0": {
                        "artifact_id": "36",
                        "timestamp": "2013-08-20 11:59:00",
                        "modified": "2013-08-20 11:59:00",
                        "text": "Why did the last one BLAHHHHH duplicate? I don't think I clicked it twice...",
                        "author_desc": "",
                        "object_type": "artifact",
                        "comments": []
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "artifact_id": "35",
                        "timestamp": "2013-08-20 11:57:51",
                        "modified": "2013-08-20 11:57:51",
                        "text": "This is a new artifact for a new day.",
                        "author_desc": "",
                        "object_type": "artifact",
                        "comments": []
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "artifact_id": "34",
                        "timestamp": "2013-08-20 11:57:50",
                        "modified": "2013-08-20 11:57:50",
                        "text": "This is a new artifact for a new day.",
                        "author_desc": "",
                        "object_type": "artifact",
                        "comments": []
                    },
                    "3": {
                        "artifact_id": "30",
                        "timestamp": "2013-08-19 13:15:32",
                        "modified": "2013-08-20 11:01:12",
                        "text": "This is some awesome text that we want to display!",
                        "author_desc": "",
                        "object_type": "artifact",
                        "comments": {
                            "5": {
                                "artifact_id": "30",
                                "comment_id": "5",
                                "user_id": "5",
                                "author_desc": "Michael C.",
                                "timestamp": "2013-08-19 16:18:12",
                                "private": "1",
                                "reported": 0,
                                "moderated": 0,
                                "banned": 0,
                                "text": "This is a createComment artifact"
                            },
                            "6": {
                                "artifact_id": "30",
                                "comment_id": "6",
                                "user_id": "5",
                                "author_desc": "Michael C.",
                                "timestamp": "2013-08-20 11:01:12",
                                "private": "1",
                                "reported": 0,
                                "moderated": 0,
                                "banned": 0,
                                "text": "This is another comment"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "4": {
                        "artifact_id": "33",
                        "timestamp": "2013-08-19 15:25:11",
                        "modified": "2013-08-19 15:25:11",
                        "text": "Kitten Ipsum dolor sit amet urna, bibendum life litora quis wish vel happy litora kitties laoreet buddy Praesent her. Lure, local ipsum amet urna molestie Nam. Snuggliest sed first chuf his cat kitten, ac climb the curtains cat eget sagittis et front",
                        "author_desc": "",
                        "object_type": "artifact",
                        "comments": []
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The goal is to iterate over the response.content.# sections. Currently i'm passing in the content through the controller (baby steps - i'm new) through a GetDigest variable. So my NGrepeater looks like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in GetDigestList.response.content">
```

How can I make it iterate over the sub sections of this json?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if content is a array

Comment: I don't have any control over the data source unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<li ng-repeat="(index, content) in GetDigestList.response.content">
   <!-- ... -->
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tdzhv/

Comment: Np.  A +1 would be nice, too :)

Comment: @flashpunk: Also note that `ng-repeat` expects its key to be unique.  You have to use `track by` to specify an index variable.  That nugget of information and the answer to this SO question are both found on Angular's documentation for `ng-repeat`, though.  It'd be worth checking out ;) http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to have content as an array you can use the $index generated by the each directive.
But just in case, check if $index don't return a string key.